# Missing module in inner compiled code

Tags: python

I'm trying to nest python scripts using compile/exec.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#file: a.py
import sys

def in_a():
    pass

print '__name__=',__name__
print 'modules[__name__]=', dir(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Running the directly gives me a list of objects which includes the in_a function.

Running it from another script using compile/code doesn't give me in_a any longer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# file: b.py
import sys

def in_b():
    pass

script = open('a.py','r').readlines()
context = dict(
      __name__='__main__',
      __file__='a.py',
   )
code = compile("\n".join(script), 'a.py', 'exec')
exec(code, context)
```

Is it possible to get a reference to the inner module inside a.py?

Comment: Not really sure how module names work with `compile`, but `b.py` should still be the `__main__` module, so your code in `a.py` reads from `b.py`'s module.

Comment: I've supplied an answer, but I'm not sure it's actually useful for you because it's not actually clear what problem you're trying to solve..  "nest python scripts" sounds a good bit like "import modules".   Is there some reason normal import machinery is not suitable for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

When  using `exec`, you don't get a module.  Module's normally arise from the import machinery.  You *could* prepare a module via the `types` module:

```
import types
someModule = types.ModuleType("anyModuleNameIsFine")
context = someModule.__dict__
context.update({'ambient': 'globals'})
exec(code, context)
```

But that seems a bit odd.  This also doesn't put them in `sys.modules`, you could *also* put them there yourself:

```
sys.modules['anyOtherName'] = someModule
```

But now we're getting dangerously close to a *custom importer*, in which case you should really just use a custom importer explicitly:

```
import imp, sys

class HelloImporter(object):

    def get_code(self, fullname):
        return "print 'hello world'"

    def is_package(self, fullname):
        return False

    def find_module(self, fn, p):
        if fn == 'hello':
            return self

    # see: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#id27
    def load_module(self, fullname):
        code = self.get_code(fullname)
        ispkg = self.is_package(fullname)
        mod = sys.modules.setdefault(fullname, imp.new_module(fullname))
        mod.__file__ = "<%s>" % self.__class__.__name__
        mod.__loader__ = self
        if ispkg:
            mod.__path__ = []
            mod.__package__ = fullname
        else:
            mod.__package__ = fullname.rpartition('.')[0]
        exec(code, mod.__dict__)
        return mod
```

To use it, add it to your `sys.meta_path`

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.meta_path.append(sa_import.HelloImporter())
>>> import hello
hello world
```